# toPrecision rounding direction

Tags: javascript, precision

Javascript's toPrecision rounds half up so

```
(123.46).toPrecision(4)    // 123.5
(123.44).toPrecision(4)    // 123.4
```

But what is a straightforward method to choose the direction of the rounding (up/ceil or down/floor)? so

```
(123.46).toPrecisionFloor(4)   // would give 123.4
(123.44).toPrecisionCeil(4)    // 123.5
```

Comment: Math.floor(123.46) ->
123

Comment: @dGRAMOP, I think DBS meant that you could *use* it (but with some additional manipulation evidently).

Comment: Ah, I misread. My bad

Answer (score 1):

It's not a one liner but I think this does what you're asking? You could probably tidy it up a little.

**EDIT** Updated (in a fairly rudimentary kind of way) to work with significant figures rather than decimals

**EDIT 2** Golfed the code down a bit and added further tests

```js
/**
 * rounds a number up or down to specified accuracy
 * @param number {numeric} number to perform operations on
 * @param precision {numeric} number of significant figures to return
 * @param direction {string} wether to round up or down
 */
function toPrecision(number, precision, direction) {
  precision -= Math.floor(number).toString().length;
  var order = Math.pow(10, precision);
  number *= order;
  var option = (direction === 'down' ? 'floor' : 'ceil');
  return (Math[option].call(null, number) / order);
}

// values to test
var test_1 = 123.567891;
var test_2 = 15000;
var test_3 = 12340000;

// define tests
var tests = {
  "a": [test_1, 3, "down"],
  "b": [test_1, 4, "up"],
  "c": [test_2, 3, "down"],
  "d": [test_2, 4, "up"],
  "e": [test_2, 1, "down"],
  "f": [test_2, 1, "up"],
  "g": [test_3, 4, "down"],
  "h": [test_3, 4, "up"]
}

// loop over tests and execute
for (var key in tests) {
  console.log("key:", key, "result: ", toPrecision.apply(null, tests[key]));
}

/*
 Test results: 
  key: a result:  123
  key: b result:  123.6
  key: c result:  15000
  key: d result:  15000
  key: e result:  10000
  key: f result:  20000
  key: g result:  12340000
  key: h result:  12340000
*/
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sauntimo/8c4p1uz9/37/)

Comment: discarded my answer, very similar to what i did except i used math.pow

Comment: I was mid way through writing something similar before I realised that `toPrecision` isn't just decimals figures, it's significant figures, which I believe makes this method inconsistent with the built in `toPrecision`, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I was going to reply: toPrecission is the total number of significant digits, not the number of decimal positions

Comment: Good points all, I've tried to edit to reflect that - is that any better?

Comment: Almost!. Try 12340000, here (node 8) gives 12299999.999999998. The problem is in that division that may introduce again imprecision. But being a divided by a power of 10 it would be just a matter of placing the decimal point in a string...

Comment: By the way the idea seems to work well on integers, needed some extensive testing though.

Comment: @tru7 I had another look at this - I've reduced the code and added further tests and I think it handles 12340000 better now - are you seeing different results to me?

Comment: @sauntimo Thanks for your efforts. The only problem is for numbers < 0.01. Here your idea of shifting the decimal point to the right until the precision does not work because the shift should be to the left the number of zeros after the decimal until the first significant digit

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I've been doing something similar. Where the scale of the number is known you can do a simple subtraction and use the precision function as is.

In my own I am trying to round to the nearest century so before I use the toPrecision function I take 50 years off the value which allows the function to produce the same ultimate result you were looking for. In the example from the original post if the precision is always going to be 4 places and the number in the format ddd.dd then you could simply remove 0.05 from the number before the precision function is called. Similarly if you wanted to round up you could add 0.05